# MediaWiki export in OpenOffice.org 3

Tags: openoffice.org, mediawiki

I've just recently found an article that describes some default functionality in OpenOffice.org 3 that isn't present in my install on 10.04 - [This entry](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Odt2Wiki#OpenOffice.org_2.4.2B) details that the Export functionality post 2.4 should have MediaWiki listed - but I only see XML,HTML, and PDF in the export options. Was this removed by the maintainers of this package in Ubuntu - or is there a package I haven't downloaded.

How do I restore this functionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ensure that `openoffice.org-wiki-publisher` is installed:.

#### [openoffice.org-wiki-publisher](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=openoffice.org-wiki-publisher) [image: Install openoffice.org-wiki-publisher]

Comment: Thanks! - I kept searching for `openoffice.org-mediawiki`