# How do I edit MediaWiki articles from LibreOffice Writer?

Tags: libreoffice, mediawiki

The [LibreOffice extentions page](http://www.libreoffice.org/features/extensions/) says that the Wiki Publisher is included as a standard feature in 3.3. This was not true for me although I am running `LibreOffice 3.3.4 OOO330m19 (Build:401) tag libreoffice-3.3.3.1, Ubuntu package 1:3.3.4-0ubuntu1`.

So, I installed the package `libreoffice-wiki-publisher` from Synaptic (same thing you [need to do in OpenOffice.org 3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3113/mediawiki-export-in-openoffice-org-3)). I did this while Writer was running, so I had to restart it for the publishing option to appear (File | Send... | To MediaWiki...)

When I click on "To MediaWiki..." I get the following error: `The MediaWiki export filter cannot be found. Choose 'Tools-XML Filter Settings' to install the filter, or use the setup to install the component.`

Is this [a bug](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=616011) or is there something else I need to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems your problem is addressed in the following bug:
http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=616011

On Ubuntu 11.10 with LibreOffice 3.4.5 I've added libreoffice-wiki-publisher and File -> Send -> To MediaWiki... works fine.

-- rpr.